# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" I'm having trouble fixing this problem. building a neural network in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, neural-network

```
def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            ans = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return ans
```

Says that `tag = intents_list[0]['intent']` is the problem.

Once I run the code, I'm supposed to be able to interact with it however it displays the error after I type anything in the terminal. I tried using an `intents_list.sort()` function, but still giving me the error.

edit:
full error displays

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xymonaesquivel/Desktop/ECE 495 Final Project/chatbot.py", line 61, in <module>
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
  File "/Users/xymonaesquivel/Desktop/ECE 495 Final Project/chatbot.py", line 43, in get_response
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Please also define all of the variables used in your code.

Comment: The calling code (which you haven't included) is apparently passing in `None` for the parameter `intents_list`. Without a [mcve] it is impossible to say why this is.

Comment: Edited. Full Error displayed

Comment: @xymonaesquivel You displayed the full error message but still haven't given enough information to solve the problem. The problem is with the function call `get_response(ints, intents)`. What is `ints`? What is `intents`? We have no idea. It seems from the message that at this point in the code `ints` is `None`. It is impossible for us to say why that is.